# Borland Starteam incorrect files status

Tags: starteam

I have some project saved in starteam. As there are a lot of obsolete files I can't check in or check out all project, only changed files. Now I copy project from one computer to another for other developer. I expect starteam treats copied project as new item for check in and check out, but it don't.

Forexample:

1. I modified file on first computer.
2. I update list of files on second computer and see this file in "check in" list, as I modified it on second computer.

It is incorrect.

I think there is some configuration file or something like, that saves computer (or user) settings. So when project is copied, settings is copied too.
Do anybody know how to change this configuration to set copied project as new instance of starteam???

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to Right-Click on either the file or a close group of files (such as the Modified group) on the file tab within a project and choose the `Update Status` option. This will cause StarTeam to analyze the file to try to determine if they truly are the same as what is in source control.  Then you can refresh the list and it should change most of your files to current.

There is also a configuration setting under Tools->Personal Options->File tab that is "Use file checksums (MD5) to calculate status".  This may be useful to you as a different way to have StarTeam determine if the file on your local disk is the same as what is in source control.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are using a custom filter/query for your check-in list.  The status for the files that are copied/moved would be "unknown" and they can still be checked-in by checking the "force check-in" checkbox in the check-in dialog.  Just verify that the local version is correct by using compare contents before committing it.

You can try switching from a central file status repository to a "per folder" repository.  This will create .sbas folders wherever you check-out files and should maintain status for local files when their containing folder is copied or moved.  Look under Tools, Personal Options on the File tab under Repository.